# MIPS noOps and bubbles

Tags: mips, no-op

Are there a specific set of MIPS operations which cause a bubble or noOp? Or is it just dependent on which registers will be needed for subsequent calls? Outside of predictive methods for branching, does a branch always cause two noOps?

```
LW R2 0(R1)
Label1:         BEQ R2 R0 Label2    #not taken once then taken
        LW R3 0(R2)
        BEQ R3 R0 Label1    #taken
        ADD R1 R3 R1
Label2      AS R1 0(R2)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture), NOP *(no operation)*:

```
sll $0,$0,0
```

I also believe that every instruction that has $0 as its destination register is a NOOP.